# Any technique for hiding ssrs reports without denying access?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have SSRS 2005 instance deployed in Sharepoint Integrated mode. There are a number of sub reports that are not intended to be used directly. They are only included as components in parent reports. Is there any way to hide them and present only the top level reports to simplify end user navigation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it's deployed in Sharepoint Integrated mode, the reports show up as list items, and you can work with them as list items.  So to hide them, you can do something like this:

1. Add a new column to the list such as "Hidden" with a Yes/No value
2. Set the Hidden value for all of the reports in the list to Yes or No, depending on whether you want them to display or to be hidden
3. Create a new view for the list, filtering to only show items where Hidden is No